# Is there a way to list installed locales on Android?

Tags: android, locale

I'm aware of `java.util.Locale` and `Locale.getAvailableLocales()` and I'm also aware of the `Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS` intent. Neither of these accomplish what I need. `Locale.getAvailableLocales()` returns all languages supported by the Android device and I need the list of locales for something special (not related to switching) so the intent doesn't help. The list that is shown for that intent is what I need though.

I've looked through the Android source for the Settings app and found the relevant code, but in using the code in the `LocalePicker`'s `onCreate` method, I am still seeing all locales supported. Is there anyway to get that list? Am I missing something in just ripping that code from the `LocalePicker`?

Answer (score 0):

If you call

```
Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
```

You'll get an array of Locales, then use

```
locale.toString();
```

to get the locale name.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that that doesn't return the list of *installed* locales; it returns a list of all *supported* locales.